# Find the user and date a filter was created in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, filtering

How do we find out which user created a filter and on what date within Google Analytics?  Google search results are sparse on this very specific topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would check out Change History tab in the admin console under ACCOUNT.

Change history lists:

- Date
- Email (who performed activity)
- Activity (e.g. account, user, view, goal, filter), and what action was performed (e.g. added to account, created, deleted).

More information in Google's Documentation - [View the history of account changes](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2949085?hl=en)

[image]